# Cannot get accurate RGB values from preloaded images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I am using MATLAB 2018 and I do not know which of the preloaded images are RGB or indexed or grayscale .... Are Color type : truecolor RGB images ? And when I copy the pixel information from a preloaded image 'onion.png' and input on impixel(1,x,y) or impixel(x,y,1) it shows 1 1 1 for the former and z z z(z is some value) for the latter... I am a beginner please help. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

onion.png is RGB. A hint for that is that it has 3 layers (size of the 3rd dimension is 3), and the type of variable is uint8. As such, its maximum is 255 and the minimum is 0, you can check it like this: `max(max(max(impixel)))`
Although Indexed images may also have 3 layers, their range is between 1 and the length of their map, and do not come in uint8. You can check map size if you read the image as

```
[impixel, map] = imread('onion.png');
```

But map is empty, onion is RGB.